# Can I relable a docker volume when I create the container?

Tags: docker

I'm following a tutorial that wants me to use podman like this:

```
podman run --mount=type=bind,src=$(pwd)/data,dst=/prometheus/data,relabel=shared --publish=127.0.0.1:9090:9090 --detach prometheus:latest
```

**But I don't want to use podman.** I'm not allowed to install podman.
I want to use docker but I can't see how to accomplish the relabel operation. There seems to be no analog in docker. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like:

```
-v "$(pwd)/data:/prometheus/data:z"
```

Documentation on configuring the selinux labels can be found at: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-the-selinux-label